# Square Root of a Holomorphic Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be an open connected subset of $\mathbb{C}$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be $even$. Let $z_1$, $z_2$,....$z_n$ be $n$ distinct complex numbers lying in the same connected component of $\mathbb{C}-U$. Show that there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on $U$ such that $(f(z))^2$=$(z-z_1)....(z-z_n)$ $\forall z \in U$.
I have managed to prove this result if $n=2$, but I am not able to genaralize it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can piece the result for $n = 2$ together to get the general case. If $f_k(z)^2 = (z - z_{2k-1})(z - z_{2k})$, then $f_1\cdot f_2 \cdot \dotsc\cdot f_{n/2}$ is a square root of $(z - z_1)\cdot\dotsc\cdot(z-z_n)$.

Comment: For n=2, I did not need the connectedness of U.Do I need it here?

Comment: No, connectedness of $U$ just reduces the number of branches to $2$ (if $f$ is one, $-f$ is the other). If $U$ has $m$ connected components, you can choose a sign on each component independently and thus have $2^m$ branches of $\sqrt{(z-z_1)\cdot\dotsc\cdot(z-z_n)}$. If $U$ has infinitely many connected components, you have $2^{\aleph_0}$ branches.

Comment: So is the result true if U is not assumed to be connected?

Comment: Yes, it is true whether or not $U$ is connected.

Comment: It couldn't possibly need $U$ connected. Because any open set is the union of a family of disjoint connected open sets - take the solutions on those components and put them together. Otoh note that it _does_ depend on the $z_j$ lying in the same component of $\Bbb C\setminus U$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer said, you can apply your result for $n=2$ and multiply the square roots of  $(z - z_{2k-1})(z - z_{2k})$, $k = 1, \ldots, \frac n2$.

Alternatively, you can show that if $z_1, \ldots, z_n$ lie in the same
component of $\Bbb C - U$ then there is a holomorphic function $g$
in $U$ such that
$$ \tag{*}
 g(z)^n = (z-z_1) \cdots (z-z_n) \, .
$$
If $n$ is even then the desired conclusion follows by choosing
$f = g^{n/2}$.

To show the existence of $g$, note that for any closed curve
$\gamma$ in $U$ the winding number $N(\gamma, z_i)$
is independent of $i$, so that
$$ 
 \frac 1n \int_\gamma \left( \frac{1}{z-z_1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{z-z_n}\right) \, dz = N(\gamma, z_1)
$$
is a multiple of $2 \pi i$. Therefore we can choose $z_0 \in U$ and define
$$
 g(z) = \exp \left( \frac 1n \int_{z_0}^z \left( \frac{1}{w-z_1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{w-z_n}\right) \, dw \right) \, .
$$
for *any* curve connecting $z_0$ with $z$
in $U$. The previous considerations show that the value is independent
of which curve is taken, so that $g$ is well-defined.

Then
$$
 h(z) = g(z)^{-n} (z-z_1)\cdots(z-z_n)
$$
satisfies
$$
\frac{h'(z)}{h(z)} = -n \frac{g'(z)}{g(z)} + \frac{1}{z-z_1} + \ldots + \frac{1}{z-z_n} = 0
$$
so that $h$ is constant in $U$. After multiplying $g$
with suitable constant, $(*)$ is satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $z_{2k-1}$ lies in the same connected component of $\Bbb C\setminus U$ as $z_{2k}$. Let $w_k(t)$ be a path that connects $w_k(0)=z_{2k-1}$ with $w_k(1)=z_{2k}$. Then the homotopy
$$
h(t,z)=\prod_{k=0}^{n/2}(z-z_{2k-1})(z-w_k(t))
$$
has at $t=0$ a square root
$$
g(0,z)=\prod_{k=0}^{n/2}(z-z_{2k-1})
$$
that has a unique continuation as square root $g(t,z)$ of $h(t,z)$. The function $g(1,z)$ solves the task.